# IIS - 401 2 5 0 Authentication Error From Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, iis-8

We have recently moved an IIS website to a new machine. The website uses Windows Authentication. There are no issues authenticating with the website when using a web browser, however when using excel power query we get the following error:

"The credentials provided for the Web source are invalid. Please update the credentials through a refresh or in the Data Source Settings dialog to continue."

And I see the following in the logs:

2021-10-21 14:20:07 10.4.14.12 GET / - 443 - 10.4.86.4 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.2;+Win64;+x64;+Trident/7.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+Tablet+PC+2.0;+wbxapp+1.0.0;+wbx+1.0.0;+Zoom+3.6.0) - 401 2 5 0

The same account is used to authenticate from the web browser as well as from excel. The migration was performed with an export of the shared configuration on the old box and an import on the new box. The only difference between the two sites are that the new site is configured with an SSL wildcard certificate.

Does anyone have any wisdom to offer?

IIS version is 8.5.
Excel version is 2016.

If Anonymous Authentication is enabled, this issue does not persist. Power query is able to pull in information.

Comment: What's the version of excel you use? The Microsoft Power Query add-in for Excel 2010/2013 is no longer being updated by Microsoft.

Comment: Excel version is 2016